# I have a book vs. I have a copy of this book

Tags: expressions

My girlfriend is not a native English speaker, so sometimes she has questions about expressions for which I do not know the origins.
This one, in particular, got me curious:

*"I have this book"* vs. *"I have a copy of this book"*

About music, you don't say:

*"I have a copy of this song"* but *"I have this song"*

Similarly, I never hear:

*"I have a copy of this DVD"* but *"I have this DVD"*

However, for books, I have commonly heard, and used myself for no special reason: *"I have a copy of this book"*

Is there a reason we sometimes refer to a book as a copy of the book?
But

Comment: The value of a book frequently depends on its edition. So an early printing may be much more valuable than a "copy" from a later edition, even though the contents are identical. The word *copy* here is used to mean a single book, often referred to for marketing purposes with its edition.

Comment: One could just as easily say "I have that book."  It just boils down to personal preference.

Comment: You got it: there is no special reason. And I've used "copy of this DVD".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, people do say they have copies of other things, it's just that books are the most common:

[image]

It's also very common to say [some song sold N million **copies**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_singles).

---

*I have X* usually means the same thing as *I have a copy of X*, except when it means *I have the original X*.

Answer (score -2):

1. *Is there a reason we sometimes refer to a book as a copy of the book?*

   ***The book*** "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest" can refer to the work of the author, however, wherever, and whenever it might have been published. It is about the **text** (content), not the physical books.

   ***A copy of the book*** "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest" refers to a particular physical (or electronic or...) *instance* of the book - not to the class of all such copies or the content (text) of the book.
2. ***I have this [or that] book*** means that the person has a copy of the book.  An individual instance (or possibly several) is understood.

   So it is not necessary to add "*a copy of*" in this context.  But it certainly doesn't hurt.  And adding that phrase can suggest a connotation that the instances possessed by the speaker might not be from the same publisher or in the same condition or of the same type (hardback or paperback; abridged or unabridged).

   The connotation can be that the speaker has a book that is *similar* to "this book", but perhaps not quite the same.

Comment: An [episode](http://www.avclub.com/tvclub/newsradio-xmas-story-and-station-sale-13118) of _Newsradio_ turned on this distinction.  For a year-end bonus, the boss gives a complete set of tapes of the old radio show _Fibber McGee And Molly_ to Matthew, who is grateful until he learns that all his co-workers received Mazda Miatas, when he becomes somewhat envious.  At the end of the episode, he learns the tapes were just a token of the actual gift: ownership of the actual show and the proceeds thereof.

Comment: Similarly, I once told a group of friends I had finished a book I was working on.  The conversation went on quite a while -- how long it had taken me, what it was about, who the publisher was -- before one friend burst out laughing:  "Oh, you finished a book you were _writing_.  I was wondering why it had taken you so long to _read_ it."

Comment: Voter: care to explain the downvote?